# How to prevent nautilus from opening new instances when it opens a mounted partition

Tags: nautilus, launcher

In Ubuntu whenever I open a mounted partition in nautilus and switch to other applications, clicking the icon of nautilus on the launcher bar will open a new instance of nautilus, instead of switching to the previously opened one. This does not happen if the already opened folder is in a linux partition. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: This is a bug reported https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1170647