# Why does nautilus open a new window when I click "Home Folder" while there is already a minimized one?

Tags: 13.04, nautilus

I am using Ubuntu 13.04.

Whenever I click on "Home Folder" on Unity it opens a new window while I already have one which I want to use. Why is that happening in 13.04? It did not happen in the previous versions. How can I solve that?

Comment: Curious. Mine doesn't unless I'm pressing *shift* while I click on the unity home folder icon.

Comment: Maybe [van](http://askubuntu.com/users/162299/van) has CapsLock activated

Comment: Or unless I click with the wheel

Comment: It happens here too. I hope it's a bug and not a functionality.

Comment: It happens without using shift or the wheel button. It is more like a bug, because sometimes when I have two windows or more, it works correctly without opening a new one.

Comment: Yes, for me sometimes it works correctly too. It also works correctly when I scroll the wheel while the cursor is on the Files icon (or "Home folder", as van called it). (Clicking using the wheel opens a new window.) 

Definitely a bug.

Comment: In my case, it opens a new window whenever I'm in a mounted partition or a mounted external drive.

Comment: I think you've found a important detail in this bug, green7. My case is the same of yours. That's why sometimes it works right, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: There is a similar recent question, which address the detail green7 has found out. Also not answered yet http://askubuntu.com/questions/286999/how-to-prevent-nautilus-from-opening-new-instances-when-it-opens-a-mounted-parti?rq=1

Comment: This is a bug reported https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1170647